# My website isn't logging the ips?

Tags: php, html, fopen, fwrite

Here is my code. I'm trying to get it so that every time a person loads my website, that it will save their ip to the txt file. But for some reason that when I load my webpage, then go check ip.txt file, it's a empty txt file and nothing is being saved. How do I fix this.

```html
<?php
    $ip = getenv("REMOTE_ADDR");
    $date = date("d") . " " . date("F") . " " . date("Y");
    $intofile = $ip . "n" . $date;
    $hfile = fopen("ip.txt", "w+");
    fwrite($hfile, $intofile);
    fclose($hfile);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>title</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" type="text/css">
  <style type="text/css">
   
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
<?php
 $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
 echo "IP: <em>$ip</em>";
?>


<!-- javascript on load page -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
   function autorun()
   {
    
   }
   if (window.addEventListener) window.addEventListener("load", autorun, false);
   else if (window.attachEvent) window.attachEvent("onload", autorun);
   else window.onload = autorun;
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Apache logs every hit by default, do you really beed to duplicate it>

Comment: What about just using your server's access logs?

Comment: @chris85 How do I do this?

Comment: thats what i said :-)

Comment: @Jackvile do what? Apache writes a log file by default

Comment: What kind of server are you running? Could be `/var/log/httpd/`.. check your configuration settings it varies by server.

Comment: @chris85 Had to do chmod a+w

Comment: @nogad had to chmod a+w

Comment: still why do something twice.

Comment: @nogad I don't know where the apache logs are. Can you tell me where they are?